# Diagram that shows how the temperature changes along a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I already have a layer that shows the average temperature in Spain.
What I want is to make a diagram or "Profile" that shows how the temperature changes along that line. (Instead of showing the height along that line like in a Profile).

I have already tried the intersect tool and got a line that has the temperature too, but I fail to create a chart that shows how the temperature changes along that line.

I tried using the "Stack profile" too, but again struggle to create the wanted chart afterwards. The table I created with stack profile doesn't have the temperature in it.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

(I initially had the average temperature as a vector layer but already produced a new raster layer if it's necessary).